# PHP finding the first matching value in 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, string-matching

I have two arrays and want to find the first match for either of arrayTwos values in arrayOne.

```
arrayOne ( [0] = C [1] = A [2] = B [3] = D [4] = B [5] = C)
```

and

```
arrayTwo ( [0] = A [1] = B [2] = C )
```

With these values I would want to return the value "C" as it is the first value in arrayTwo to appear in arrayOne.

I'm thinking I could use for loops and if statements to run through but re there any functions in PHP I could use to simplify this?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php - your answer likely lies in wait here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_search`

```
$keys = array_search($second_array, $first_array);
```

Ref : https://www.php.net/array_search

Comment: so this returns only the first found value? perfect. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

use [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/array_intersect)

```
$arrayOne = array('C', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'B', 'C');
$arrayTwo = array('A', 'C');
$result = array_intersect($arrayOne , $arrayTwo);
echo $result[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_intersect`. This will do the job. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php Note the difference between using `array_intersect($array1, $array2)` and `array_intersect($array2, $array1)`

Answer (score 0):

[array_search](http://php.net/array_search)

```
$valuekeys = array_search($secondarray, $arrayone);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_intersect()`:

```
$arr1 = array( 0 => 'C', 1 => 'A', 2 => 'B', 3 => 'D', 4 => 'B', 5 => 'C');
$arr2 = array( 0 => 'A', 1 => 'B', '2' => 'C' );
$arr3 = array_intersect($arr1,$arr2);
var_dump($arr3[0]);
string(1) "C"
```